# How to run a single ECS task in only one EC2 instance using auto scaling and capacity provider?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-ecs, aws-auto-scaling

I am using Terraform to create an ECS cluster with an EC2 instance. My goal is to have a single task running on only one EC2 instance. I am managing both the capacity provider and auto-scaling for this cluster.

Initially, the deployment of a task to an EC2 instance runs smoothly. However, when I try to deploy a new task definition to replace the existing task, the ECS keeps the task in a PROVISIONING state. The task stays in this state until I change the auto-scaling group's max_size from 1 to 2.
Once I do that, the new task deployment is done in a new EC2 instance, and the previous instance is removed after some time as a action related to a CloudWatch alarm (CapacityProviderReservation < 100 for 15 datapoints within 15 minutes).

For now, in my non-production environment, I want to keep only one instance as part of my cluster and allow multiple deployments of the same task on the same instance.

Terraform code:

```
# ECS service
resource "aws_ecs_service" "this" {
  name                 = "cluster"
  iam_role             = aws_iam_role.ecs_role.arn
  cluster              = aws_ecs_cluster.cluster.id
  task_definition      = aws_ecs_task_definition.task_definition.arn
  desired_count        = 1
  force_new_deployment = true

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.lb.arn
    container_name   = aws_ecs_task_definition.task_definition.family
    container_port   = 80
  }

  ordered_placement_strategy {
    type  = "binpack"
    field = "memory"
  }

  capacity_provider_strategy {
    capacity_provider = aws_ecs_capacity_provider.ecs_capacity_provider.name
    base              = 1
    weight            = 100
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
    ignore_changes = [
      desired_count
    ]
  }

}
```

```
# Auto scaling
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "ecs_asg" {
  name                  = "asg"
  vpc_zone_identifier   = [for subnet in var.public_subnet_ids : subnet]
  max_size              = 1
  min_size              = 1
  desired_capacity      = 1
  health_check_type     = "EC2"
  protect_from_scale_in = false

  launch_template {
    id      = aws_launch_template.template.id
    version = "$Latest"
  }

  instance_refresh {
    strategy = "Rolling"
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

}
```

```
# capacity provider
resource "aws_ecs_capacity_provider" "ecs_capacity_provider" {
  name = "ecs_capacity_provider"

  auto_scaling_group_provider {
    auto_scaling_group_arn         = aws_autoscaling_group.ecs_asg.arn
    managed_termination_protection = "DISABLED"

    managed_scaling {
      maximum_scaling_step_size = 2
      minimum_scaling_step_size = 1
      status                    = "ENABLED"
      target_capacity           = 100
    }
  }

}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster_capacity_providers" "ecs_capacity_providers" {
  cluster_name = aws_ecs_cluster.cluster.name

  capacity_providers = [aws_ecs_capacity_provider.ecs_capacity_provider.name]

  default_capacity_provider_strategy {
    base              = 1
    weight            = 100
    capacity_provider = aws_ecs_capacity_provider.ecs_capacity_provider.name
  }

}
```

```
# ECS Task
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task" {
  family = "task"
  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      name      = "task",
      image     = "test",
      cpu       = "768",
      memory    = "4096",
      essential = true
      portMappings = [
        {
          containerPort = 80
          hostPort      = 80
          protocol      = "tcp"
        }
      ]
      logConfiguration = {
        logDriver = "awslogs",
        options = {
          "awslogs-group"         = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.logs.name,
          "awslogs-region"        = var.region,
          "awslogs-stream-prefix" = "app"
        }
      }
    }
  ])
  execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.ecs_exec.arn
  task_role_arn      = aws_iam_role.ecs_task.arn

}
```

I noticed there is a related cloud watch alarm being triggered when I try the second task deployment which is linked to the auto scaling:

Alarm: "TargetTracking-test-ecs-asg-AlarmHigh-e5a4556-5686-5669-26546-e745a5ed90cb"

[image]

Comment: It sounds like one or both of the CPU or RAM values for your ECS task is causing ECS to think it can only run one of those tasks on the EC2 instance size you chose.  Can you show the ECS task settings, and the EC2 instance type you are using?

Comment: @MarkB I just updated the Terraform code related to my question to reflect my ecs service, ecs task cpu/mem and capacity provider default values. Regarding instance type = i3.large. Could you please check it again?